# How to get data from two tables if they have matches and if they don't?

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I've read that when I use LEFT JOIN,

> Each item in the left table will show up in a MySQL result, even if there isn't a match with the other table that it is being joined to.

And this is what I'm planning to use in my query since I want to find matches from `alumni.name` with `profile.name` and still result all records from `alumni` table, and only matched records from `profile` table. That's how I understood LEFT JOIN. Did I understand it correctly? Tell me if I didn't.

If I am correct, then I have another problem. Because I want that when `alumni.name` didn't match with `profile.name`, records from two tables will still print.

Something like this

```
if alumni.name==profile.name
    output alumni.name
else if alumni.name != profile.name
    output alumni.name and profile.name
```

This is just a sample on how I want to do it. Don't judge my condition, I know that isn't the correct way, but my idea is like that. Hope you can help me.

Sample snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table width="30%" align="center">
<th> Alumni ID </th>
<th> Alumni Firstname </th>
<th> Alumni Lastname </th>

  <tr align="center">
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
  </tr>
 
  <tr align="center">
     <td> 2 </td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
 <td> 3 </td>
    <td>Ed</td>
    <td>Fin</td>  
  </tr>

</table>
<br><br>

<table width="30%" align="center">
<th> Profile ID </th>
<th> Profile Firstname </th>
<th> Profile Lastname </th>

  <tr align="center">
   <td> 1 </td>
    <td>Ed</td>
    <td>Fin</td>  
  </tr>
 
  <tr align="center">
   <td> 2 </td>
    <td>Ricky</td>
    <td>Perez</td> 
 
  <tr align="center">
   <td> 3 </td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
  </tr>
  
</table>

<table width="30%" align="center">
<center><h4>EXPECTED OUTPUT </h4></center>
<th> ID </th>
<th> Firstname </th>
<th> Lastname </th>

  <tr align="center">
   <td> 1 (from table alumni)</td>
    <td>Jill </td>
    <td>Smith </td>  
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
   <td> 2 (from tbl alumni)</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
   <td> 2 (from tbl profile)</td>
    <td>Ricky</td>
    <td>Perez</td>  
  </tr>
    <tr align="center">
   <td> 3 (from tbl alumni)</td>
    <td>Ed</td>
    <td>Fin</td>  
  </tr>
    
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not show two table structures with data inserted on it and expected output.

Comment: So you are just asking if your understanding of left-join is correct or are you asking for a way to run a join query on a database with php? I'm saying this because of the `php` and `mysqli` tags

Comment: `CASE` is your statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: Okay, I will. @BikashP

Comment: your question is not quite clear, may be setup sqlfiddle with your table structure

Comment: Both actually @dimlucas But if I was correct, then I know how to run join query, I just do not know which join query to use with my expected output like that.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT IF(alumni.name=profile.name, alumni.name, CONCAT(alumni.name, ' ', profile.name)) AS name 
FROM alumni 
LEFT JOIN profile ON alumni.indexkey = profile.fkey

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way..

```
SELECT (CASE when (colname1 = "XYZ" colname2 = "ABC") 
 THEN
      1 
 ELSE
      0 
 END)
 as res from mytbl;
```